# exec.Command with input redirection

Tags: bash, go

I'm trying to run a fairly simple bash command from my Go code.  My program writes out an IPTables config file and I need to issue a command to make IPTables refresh from this config.  This is very straightforward at the commandline:

`/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf`

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to issue this command with exec.Command().  I tried a few things to accomplish this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/sbin/iptables-restore", "<", "/etc/iptables.conf")
// And also
cmd := exec.Command("/sbin/iptables-restore", "< /etc/iptables.conf")
```

No surprise, neither of those worked.  I also tried to feed the filename into the command by piping in the file name to stdin:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/sbin/iptables-restore")
stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

err = cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

io.WriteString(stdin, "/etc/iptables.conf")
```

That doesn't work either, no surprise.  I *can* use stdin to pipe in the contents of the file, but this seems silly when I can just tell iptables-restore what data to go read.  So how might I get Go to run the command `/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first read this `/etc/iptables.conf` file content then write it to `cmd.StdinPipe()`  like this:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/etc/iptables.conf")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    cmd := exec.Command("/sbin/iptables-restore")
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = io.WriteString(stdin, string(bytes))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd thought of this, and had mocked it up with a static string as a test.  It works.  However, I was hoping that I could do this without dumping the contents of the data into a pipe like this.  However, if it's the only way, that'll have to do.

Comment: calling like ` exec.Command("/sbin/iptables-restore", "<", "/etc/iptables.conf")` will not work: the "<" and  "/etc/iptables.conf" used as Args to "/sbin/iptables-restore".  I think you need `exec.Command("/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf")` but this doesn't work either. with error:file not found(in my case), you may call one external shell file which it calls "/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf".

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd := exec.Command("/usr/sbin/iptables-restore", "--binary", iptablesFilePath)
_, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
return nil
```

this work fine on my Raspberry Pi3